# R cannot be resolved to a variable after adding image

Tags: java, android

Got problem with "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

I started a new project and everything was running fine, but then I added 2 images to the folder drawable-hdpi and the error on R started coming.

I updated the SDK, still nothing worked.

```
[2014-04-03 14:21:57 - Smörgåsbord] res\drawable-hdpi\qr.scanner.pressed.png:0:                      error: Resource entry qr is already defined.
[2014-04-03 14:21:57 - Smörgåsbord] res\drawable-hdpi\qr.scanner.normal.png:0: Originally defined here.
[2014-04-03 14:24:54 - Smörgåsbord] res\drawable-hdpi\qr.scanner.pressed.png:0:                   error: Resource entry qr is already defined.
[2014-04-03 14:24:54 - Smörgåsbord] res\drawable-hdpi\qr.scanner.normal.png:0: Originally defined here.
[2014-04-03 14:27:26 - Smörgåsbord] res\drawable-hdpi\qr.scanner.pressed.png:0: error: Resource entry qr is already defined.
```

(Can't post a image because I'm new around here...)

Comment: Do you have `qr.scanner.pressed.jpg` also in folders? If yes then delete .jpg image files.

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice to use dots in resource names. You should use underscores instead, like qr_scanner_pressed.png.

Comment: You cant post the image, but you can always post the link of the image to other image server. We will updated the image in your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

remove `.` from your image name and replace with `_` sign then your image will look like this:

qr_scanner_pressed.png

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project or build the project by pressing `ctrl+b`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `R` class is not found is because Android SDK could not generated it due to errors in your resources.

Android SDK does not like dots `.` in file names - other than to separate the extensions. It takes part of name up to the first dot and tries to use that as the name of the member variable in `R` when generating it.  In your case, you have

```
qr.scanner.pressed.png
qr.scanner.normal.png
```

Android takes part up to the first dot only and tries to create in the `R.java`:

```
public final static int qr = xxxxxxx;   //this is for qr.scanner.pressed.png
public final static int qr = yyyyyyy;   //this is for qr.scanner.normal.png
```

When compiled, this produces errors - as you posted in your question - and as a result, `R` class is not generated and can't be found.

As @HarshitRathi stated, rename the files to have `_` instead of dots:

```
qr_scanner_pressed.png
qr_scanner_normal.png
```

Then refresh the `resources` folder (select it in the tree in Eclipse and press F5) - and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The image or any resource shouldn't contains neither special characters nor spaces nor capital letter nor start with a number.

All this limitation is that, because this file name or even the given ID will be resolved into a declared variable in the generated class R.java file.

So, in your case you should imagine that, the image file name is valid to be declared as a variable name or not.

Answer (score 0):

Extension name of your image shouldn’t be upper case. If your image’s name ends with `.PNG` change it to `.png`. Good luck.